# Scala: diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Writes/Reads

Tags: scala, play-json

I am reading this tutorial: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJson

**1.** In a Play/Scala controller I have the following:

```
def myAction  = Action.async { request: MessagesRequest[AnyContent] =>
    Future {
        case class MyData(first: Int, second: Int)

        implicit val myDataWrites = new Writes[MyData] {            
            def writes(myData: MyData) = Json.obj(
                "first"  -> myData.first,
                "second" -> myData.second
            )
        }

        Ok(Json.toJson("result" -> new MyData(1, 1)))
    }
}
```

When I compile from the command line, I am getting the following error:

```
[error] diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Reads[MyData]
[error] starting with method GenericFormat in trait DefaultFormat
[error]       Ok(Json.toJson("result" -> new MyData(1, 1)))
[error]                     ^
[error] one error found
```

It seems to me like I've been following the instructions in the tutorial:

> To convert your own models to JsValues, you must define implicit
> Writes converters and provide them in scope.

**What is missing here?**

**2.** If I change the code to:

```
case class MoreData(a: Long, b: Long)
implicit val reads: Reads[MoreData] = Json.reads[MoreData]

def myAction  = Action.async(parse.json[MoreData]) { request =>
    Future {
        case class MyData(first: Int, second: Int)

        implicit val myDataWrites = new Writes[MyData] {            
            def writes(myData: MyData) = Json.obj(
                "first"  -> myData.first,
                "second" -> myData.second
            )
        }

        Ok(Json.toJson("result" -> new MyData(1, 1)))
    }
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
[error] diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Writes[(String, MyData)]
[error] starting with method GenericFormat in trait DefaultFormat
[error]       Ok(Json.toJson("result" -> new MyData(1, 1)))
[error]                     ^
[error] one error found
```

Again, I don't understand this. It seems like there is `Writes[MyData]` in the scope, and it seems like there is only one. So why doesn't it work?

And why did using  `parse.json[MoreData]` change the error compilation from `Reads` to `Writes`?

**3.** Also, I wrote this code in `Intellij`. Which usually highlights compilation errors. For example, if I remove the implicit `myDataWrites`, intellij does highlight a compilation error. But with the code above it does not highlight anything.

**Why is that?**

Comment: The error is a bit unclear to me in this situation but I see a potential issue: how do you expect to write a tuple `(String, MyData)` to JSON? I don't think there any `Writes` for tuples in Play JSON. Did you mean to create a wrapper JSON object?

Comment: @GaëlJ Tuple is not the problem here. You can change the last line to `Ok(Json.toJson(MyData(1, 1)))` and get similar error: `diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Reads[MyData]`. You can change the last line to `Ok(Json.toJson("result" -> "okay"))` and the code will compile successfully.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example then? I do not reproduce with the code you provided: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/OdaeKqJsR8emPxCkzjfBYw

Comment: I've tried my code above in a new clean Play project and it compiled (and ran fine). But it does not compile in my project (which is quite large). Is there anything outside of this class that can interfere with this code? I define all the variables inside the Action method, so is it still possible to do something outside of this method that would make the code not compile (and with error I cited above)?

Comment: Did you mean to do `Json.obj("result" -> MyData(1,1))` ?

Comment: @Dylan Either of them compiles or doesn't compile.

Comment: @GaëlJ My controller https://scastie.scala-lang.org/GswKb9BBRJWDM57SxngVYA

Comment: Try this https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7A4aDHKVTRCiAvOJWHH4Uw

Comment: @Dylan In my actual project it still gives me the same compilation error `diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Reads[MyData]`. In a new Play project it compiles.